# Where in Java Swing Source is the implementation of the Enter Keypress on a menu?

Tags: java, swing, keypress, custom-component, jmenu

I am mucking around with a hierarchical menu trying to make it scrollable.  Yes, I know about Menu Scroller at the Java Tips Weblog, but it doesn't quite do what I want, so I've been mucking about with a stripped down version of it it and I'm not quite getting it to work.

Basically I want a JMenu with too many items to display on which the user can press the up and down arrow keys to scroll the menu.  I have gotten tanatalizingly close to what I want but I have come to a hurdle which I can best describe this way:

When [ENTER] is pressed while a popup menu has focus, default behavior is to do the action associated with the selected item and dispose of the menu.  If the menu is nested, popups above it in the hierarchy also close (become invisible).  Where is this behavior coded?  I've looked all over JMenu, JPopupMenu, JMenuItem, AbstractButton and I don't see what I am looking for.  Where is the Swing source code that executes this common behavior?

If I knew the answer to that, I might understand why my implementation isn't working.  I can do the action, but the menu and its parents won't disappear. I can make the menu disappear by setVisible(false) of course, but I can't walk the containment hierarchy to find the parent menus and make THEM disappear.

Comment: It's likely to be in the UI delegate code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can do the action, but the menu and its parents won't disappear.

I think you can use:

```
MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath()
```

Comment: Wonderful.  Just what I needed!  Thanks, Rob!  Thanks for reading through my dense late night question and sussing out what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain for menus, but I know for `JTextComponent`s that all of the keystrokes (copy, paste, enter, move forward by words/sentences/lines, deleting, etc.) are implemented via the [`InputMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap%28%29) and [`ActionMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getActionMap%28%29). `JTextcomponent`s also use [`Keymap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Keymap.html)s, but I'm pretty sure those are specific to text components.